# find CallBack fires more than once sometimes

Tags: parse-platform, titanium, titanium-alloy

Im fetching data from from Parse and try to show it. Problem im facing right now is find callback is firing multiple times sometimes. How can I stop this?
Thanks.

```
var args = [];

query.find({
    success : function(results ) {

        args = {
            name : results[0].get('name'),
            address : results[0].get('address'),
            sex : results[0].get('sex'),
            email : results[0].get('email'),
            age : results[0].get('age')
        };
        var personView = Alloy.createController("personDetails", args).getView();
        if (OS_IOS) {
            $.navGroupWin.openWindow(personView);
        }
        if (OS_ANDROID) {
            personView.open();
        }   // args1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args));
        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    },
```

Comment: weird. Is it possible to upload a simplified application to github? (just simple enough to reproduce the bug, remove anything else)

Comment: what version of ti sdk and alloy are you using?

Comment: @phil TI sdk: 3.3.0.RC2 and from where i can find out Alloy version?

Comment: run "alloy -v" in the terminal or check your tiapp.xml

Comment: I dunno if it's an issue in the RC2 or not, if it were me I'd prefer to rule that out by installing one of the GA releases

Comment: for GA i need xocde 6 and for xocode 6 i need latest Mac os version right?

Comment: I think that's correct, yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. Here is how I fixed it:

```
var succInvoked = false;

query.find({
    success : function(results ) {

        if (succInvoked) {
            return;
        }

        succInvoked = true;

        // your success callback here

    },
```

Comment: Late answer and exactly the same thing I did :)

Comment: This seems related to this [issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17704). And it's fixed in the latest version 3.5 of Titanium.